# Typeahead using angular-ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, typeahead

I have created a typeahead using the angular-ui library.

My current typeahead html is:

```
<input name="customers" id="customers" type="text" placeholder="enter a customer" ng-model="selectedCustomer" uib-typeahead="customer.firstName for customer in customers  | filter: $viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" typeahead-editable="false">
```

Basically the typeahead search works ok but when i select the type ahead i want to retrieve all the fields which are attached to the customer record such as surname , address etc. The typeahead gets populated into property called $scope.customers in my controller which is done via an ajax call to the api to get all customers.

So on selection how can i get all the fields related to the selected customer?

Cheers

Comment: Are you asking how to know when the typeahead is triggered or how to do the ajax call? I guess I'm missing the question.

Comment: No i want to know when i select the option in the typeahead there is a customer record which has been used to populate the typeahead but i am only showing the firstname. Basically on selection of that i want to get the other properties such as surname etc. Hope that makes sense

Comment: From an Ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the uib-typeahead attribute:

```
<input name="customers" id="customers" type="text" placeholder="enter a customer" ng-model="selectedCustomer" uib-typeahead="customer as customer.firstName for customer in customers  | filter: $viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" typeahead-editable="false">
```

This will set the selected customer to the ng-model `selectedCustomer`.